# Select item by a maximum value and duplicates of this value present in List<Tuple>

Tags: c#, list, linq, tuples, max

Print top value and its  duplicate values present in List
Suppose List is ordered list.

```
List<Tuple<int, string, string>> result = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>> {
    {4, "am", "I am the One"}
    {4, "am" , "I am human"}
    {2, "one", "zero plus one is one"}
    {1, "is", "this is list"}
};
```

Selected output should Top int value and its duplicate if present.

Top according to int values is : 4. Duplicates are 1st and 2nd entries of list.

Output:

```
4, am, I am the One
4, am , I am human
```

Can anyone code to get max value and its duplicate?

Comment: "Can anyone code..." of course, what's the salary you offer? counterproposal: Please post an attempt of yours and explain in detail the problem you are having with this approach, and we help you to solve this problem

Comment: I didn't mean to say what you understood.
I tried different ways to code but getting exception and other problems.
Just for typing precisely, i just added requirement only.
Code can be 1 liner too just for getting idea how to code properly for getting required result.

Comment: Have a look at LINQ particularly First and GroupBy.

Comment: off topic. I see you haven't accepted any of the answers to any of your qestions. If you don't know how to do it [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help. People here will be more inclined to help you if you display the courtesy of returning the favor

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: OK. 
Alright!
Tried Linq different queries. Don't understand how to do it.

Comment: If you tried something then you can post that code and explain what didn't work with it..

Comment: Thanks! @d219 
Let me try this.

Comment: @GiladGreen I tried many different code and removed after not getting required result and exceptions.
Wait! I'll redo and will show you.

Comment: @Nab - the reason I ask is that this website is to help correct code you have tried. Without showing any code it is as if you didn't try and just ask for  us to code for you..

Comment: I used GroupBy but not with first.
@d219

Comment: Actually don't think you'll need group by now I can better see what you'r trying to do. Is it the record with the Max int you are after (rather than first).

Comment: OK @GiladGreen I got it.

Comment: @d219 I tried max, findall, hardcode, and other stuff.
But there is something that I am missing for sure.
Once I ordered list then I don't need maximum integer.
first will work.

Comment: Actually, I was testing code as final touch to include it in original program.
Resolving issues by giving different input, and stuck here.

Comment: @GiladGreen Why did you delete your answer?
I really liked it. I was thinking to select that answer but it disappeared.
I need query in which you used First.

Comment: But how did you delete and then brought it back as same as it was earlier?

Comment: @MongZhu Hope, you are cooled down now. 
I selected answers.

Comment: OK. @TobySpeight
I deleted my comment posted as answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight Are you downvoting answer and post?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
List<Tuple<int, string, string>> maxTuples = 
    result.Where(r => r.Item1 == (result.Max(m => m.Item1))).ToList();
```

You are getting the maximum value of Item1 (the int) and then finding all records that have the same value.

HTH, like mentioned in the comments previously good to post what you have tried in future.

Comment: Thank you so much. :)
I was missing (m => m.Item1) probably.
By this query, I also don't need ordered list too.
I wanted to try First, will do it later.

Comment: No worries @Nab. Someone has but given no reason for it, ah well not the end of the world. Glad we got you on the right path anyhow! :)

Comment: Nope, not me, don't think there's anyway to see who's done it. I've just edited the title to make it a bit clearer but not down voted (not sure if I can down vote either actually) @Nab

Comment: Oh! OK.
Whoever downvoting, please type reason.